# How to start scrolling UIPickerView before it's visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipickerview

I want to start dragging and make it visible at the same time. 
As of now, I have to click a button to make the pickerview visible and then scroll to select the desired row. How can I start the selection as soon as I start dragging from the button?

I tried to illustrate both cases in this [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzC8B.jpg).

Comment: Sorry to be a downer, but I'd go with what you have. UIPickerViews have very little in the way of custom/programmatic scrolling, and UIViews don't receive touch events when hidden. The only quasi-solution I can think of would be to set the alpha to the minimum non-zero value then set it to 1 when it starts scrolling (you can tell when it starts scrolling because it will call its delegate methods; viewForRow, titleForRow etc.) If that doesn't work, I'm sure there are third party libs out there for more customizable picker views. Raid the github.

Comment: I've been testing a bit now, and although it actually works setting the alpha close to zero in the delegate methods, it wasnt't the smooth user experience I was going for. Thanks a lot though! Feel free to submit your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the alpha to the minimum non-zero value then set it to 1 when it starts scrolling (you can tell when it starts scrolling because it will call its delegate methods; viewForRow, titleForRow etc.) Not a perfect solution but might work for you.